# Calculate aggregated sum from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

From the following tables I need to determine which city receives the most pollution from buses.

routes:

```
route_id | departure_city | destination_city | bus_type | times_per_day
 1         2                1                  1          4
 2         1                3                  2          2
 3         3                1                  2          1
 4         1                2                  1          5
 5         1                3                  1          3
```

bustypes:

```
bus_type_id | pollution_output
 1             3
 2             7
```

For example city 2 is exposed to bus_type 1 four times a day (route_id 1) and bus_type 1 five times a day (route_id 4) giving a pollution output of 27 per day. But I basically need to calculate this for all the cities and return the one with maximum pollution, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT city, sum(pollution) AS total_pollution
FROM (
   SELECT r.depature_city AS city
         ,b.pollution_output * r.times_per_day AS pollution
   FROM   routes   r
   JOIN   bustypes b ON b.bus_type_id = r.bus_type

   UNION ALL
   SELECT r.destination_city
         ,b.pollution_output * r.times_per_day
   FROM   routes   r
   JOIN   bustypes b ON b.bus_type_id = r.bus_type
   ) AS sub
GROUP  BY city
```